# how to protect images from downloading from web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to protect my images from web pages. No one should be able to download them.
I tried 64 bit encryption but i was not able to display that string again in image format.
Is there any other option.
or can is there any tutorial available for 64 bit encryption

Comment: if user can see , then user can download them

Comment: maybe use a watermark on the images if it's possible.

Comment: What can stop me to do printscreen?

Comment: The only thing you can really prevent is direct access to the image using htaccess, but users can always print screen :)

Comment: You can prevent direct access, but deal with it - somebody will download it. Istead, put there some copyright so you can press charges if anyone use those pictures.

Answer (score 2):

You can't ! If they can see them means the images are acctually downloaded to their machines, technically !

Comment: Actually, it's a fair, if badly spelt point. Fundamentally, if the user can see the images, then the client pc has downloaded them (and thus could save them).
The original poster could ask on ways to make this harder, but that would be a different (and probably `too broad`) question.